# Deep Filtering Array of Objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

We're trying to wrap our heads around this for awhile and can't seem to get what we're looking for.  We've attempted many loops and using lodash library to make this possible but no success. We want to loop through the arrays and return any objects and children that have the property `checked:true` or remove the objects that have `checked: false`. There are multiple levels deep and we're not able to return what we're looking for

```
types: [
  {
    name: 'Dresses',
    checked: true,
    collections: [
      {
        name: 'My Collection',
        checked: true,
        variations: [
          { 
            size: 'XXS',
            checked: true

          },
          { 
            size: 'XS',
            checked: false

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'False Collection',
        checked: false,
        variations: [
          { 
            size: 'XXS',
            checked: false

          },
          { 
            size: 'XS',
            checked: false

          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Tops',
    checked: true,
    collections: [
      {
        name: 'Another Collection',
        checked: true,
        variations: [
          { 
            size: 'XXS',
            checked: false

          },
          { 
            size: 'XS',
            checked: true

          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Our Expected output that we are trying to generate would be:

```
types: [
      {
        name: 'Dresses',
        checked: true,
        collections: [
          {
            name: 'My Collection',
            checked: true,
            variations: [
              { 
                size: 'XXS',
                checked: true

              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Tops',
        checked: true,
        collections: [
          {
            name: 'Another Collection',
            checked: true,
            variations: [
              { 
                size: 'XS',
                checked: true

              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Which removes any object with the property `checked: false`

Comment: Can you post your expected result from your provided input?

Comment: IS this similar to your need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483706/javascript-how-to-filter-deep-json-objects

Comment: Are you saying that `variations` might also have nested `collections`?

Comment: What happens to a `checked: true` object nested in a `checked: false` one?

Comment: so can we assume `checked: flase,` is just a typo? Show what you have attempted WITH the result expected, we can help fix things :)

Comment: @FrankerZ I posted the expected result.  Basically we want to remove all objects with `checked: false`

Comment: @ScottSauyet the children are removed with the parent and don't need to be preserved

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lodash, I suggest to use [filterDeep](https://deepdash.io/#filterdeep) method from `deepdash`:

```
var filtrate = _.filterDeep(types, function(value, key, parent) {
  if (parent.checked) return true;
});
```

Here is a [test](https://github.com/YuriGor/deepdash/blob/cfaea96143bae83fc00d03f2e7fea425be298ef0/test/stackoverflow.js#L124) for your case

Answer (score 0):

I usually choose to use [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) for such problems.  (Disclaimer: I'm one of its authors.)  With Ramda, you could do it like this:

```js
const types = [{"checked": true, "collections": [{"checked": true, "name": "My Collection", "variations": [{"checked": true, "size": "XXS"}]}], "name": "Dresses"}, {"checked": true, "collections": [{"checked": true, "name": "Another Collection", "variations": [{"checked": true, "size": "XS"}]}], "name": "Tops"}]

const {is, filter, pipe, toPairs, map, fromPairs} = R;
 
const onlyChecked = (obj) => 
  is(Array, obj) 
  ? filter(onlyChecked, obj)
  : is(Object, obj)
    ? pipe(
        toPairs,
        filter(([key, val]) => val.checked !== false),
        map(([key, val]) => [key, onlyChecked(val)]),
        fromPairs
      )(obj)
    : obj;

console.log(onlyChecked(types))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

This should be easy to port to lodash, as the key functions such as `fromPairs` and `toPairs` are included in both, and Ramda's `is(Array)`/`is(Object)` are very similar to lodash's `isArray`/`isObject`.

Comment: Hey @scottsauyet thanks for posting. We will have to look into Rhamda since we have not used it before. The answer looks pretty succinct so we will have to dissect it and give it a shot. We'll upvote if the answer works for us.

Comment: Looking back at that answer, it seems to me to make no sense.  I will try to look at it again tonight.

Comment: hey thanks for taking a look.  After running your function with Ramda we were not able to return the results we wanted. It seems to be returning all the results not just the "checked": true objects